# Efficient way to count string values across multiple columns to create new total column

Tags: python, pandas, survey

I have a dataframe of survey responses with 'Yes/No' responses. I would like to create a new column/variable that is the total number of Yes responses.

[image]

I could replace all the 'Yes/No' to '1/0', then use:

```
df['total_variable'] = df.iloc[:, 16:22].sum(axis=1)
```

Or I could write a for loop.

But I was just wondering if there are any other efficient ways of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead replacing compare by `Yes` by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and then count `True`s by `sum`:

```
df['total_variable'] = df.iloc[:, 16:22].eq('Yes').sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Amazing! I had never come across DataFrame.eq before. This will be very handy for the future. Thanks!