# Counting "Yes" Responses across columns in Python

Tags: python

I have a data frame that contains multiple columns that identify if a "Yes" or "No" response based on various conditions.
[Table_Exmaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A5cP.png)

I am trying to create a new column that counts the "Yes" responses across these conditions. New column:
[Table_with_new_Count_Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S84Ta.png)

I tried the solution from this other question [Efficient way to count string values across multiple columns to create new total column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793741/efficient-way-to-count-string-values-across-multiple-columns-to-create-new-total)

and variations of it from other posts, but keep getting errors, most commonly:

```
df2['Count'] = df2.iloc[:, 0:9].eq('Yes').sum(axis=1)

<ipython-input-21-189874c017d3>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

See the caveats in the documentation:   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
`df2['Count'] = df2.iloc[:, 0:9].eq('Yes').sum(axis=1)`

I've looked everywhere and am probably missing something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there's issue in this code snippet. It would be better if you can provide value of data. As it's correct and giving desired output also.

Answer (score 0):

Basically,  construct a new column or columns with numeric values to represent yes or no.  So yes=1, no=0. Then can add those to get a total or whatever else is desired.

This would work:

```py
import pandas as pd

# create a dtaframe example
d = {'col_1':['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes'],
    'col_2':['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# create a function to test string
def yes_or_no(x):
    if x=='yes':
        return 1
    if x=='no':
        return 0
    return 'error'

# apply the function
df['col_3']=df['col_1'].apply(yes_or_no)

# print the result
y = df['col_3'].sum()
print('number of yes', y)
```

result:

```
number of yes 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below, this is tested and working

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dtaframe example
d = {'c1': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'],
     'c2': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'],
     'c3': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'],
     'c4': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes'],
     'c5': ['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes']
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['count'] = df.iloc[:, :].eq('Yes').sum(axis=1)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions provided so far I have gotten the same response. However, I found this other post speaking directly to the error message I received. I tried that and it worked for my original code.
Thank you all. I appreciate your guidance.

Other post for reference.

[How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).